# How to set location flags in code and easily jump back

Tags: intellij-idea

Emacs has the notion of [position registers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Position-Registers.html). You can store the location of your cursor (buffer + location) in a register. And when you're somewhere else in your project you can relatively easy jump to this stored position.

Is there something similar for IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is something similar for IntelliJ, and for many other modern IDEs and editors. it is called ***bookmarks***.

Comment: could have known.